# Server specific super slow SQL update command

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a MYISAM database on MySQL 5.5.31 that is running the following update

```
UPDATE tableA AS a
INNER JOIN tableB AS b
ON((a.id = b.dnum and a.account = b.account) 
   OR a.id = CONCAT(b.dnum, '\_', b.account, '\_', b.unique))
SET a.status = 0, a.apd = NULL WHERE a.status = 1;
```

I have tried running this query on 3 different test machines using an identical set of data and nearly identical mysql setup and the query completes in 1 second or less updating around 25000 rows.

Running this query on the production server and it never completes, I have killed it after 40+ minutes.

The major differences in configuration between test boxes and production is the MySQL version which is 5.5.41 and the production system has a replication log all cache sizes etc are the same.

I have found a work around which is to run a select and create 25000+ update statements and this process manages to run in 2-3 second on production. However, I am concerned that production's SQL performance is so radically different from the testing environments that the horribly slow performance issue can occur in unexpected places.

I created a new test database on the production server and imported the data into this and it had the same terrible performance, so it appears to be specific to this server's configuration. In general SQL performance seems fine, this so far this is the only query which is clearly dramatically different in performance terms.

I thought the cause could be the replication, which is set to row level and so it would need to generate a couple of thousand row updates in the bin log, but I added *SET @@session.sql_log_bin=0;* and *SET @@session.sql_log_bin=1;* either side of the SQL on the new test database and it did not seem to make a difference. Also I configured a test box to write to a bin log (but did not set up a slave) and this did not have a large impact on performance.

Does anyone have any idea how I can determine any possible cause for this database not performing this query at a reasonable level, or any diagnostics to find out what is going on?

Comment: do you run it directly on mysql server? or is there some php or other language/framework/cms that you are using to call the query?

Comment: Try running your query twice, once with each set of join conditions rathering than OR-ing them together.

Comment: do a `select` instead and explain, of if you have 5.6+ just explain the query. Its likely your missing an index and your getting to the last condition which will be slow

Comment: I am running these queries via MySQL workbench on three different servers. Production server performance is 40 minutes+, test 1 0.091 seconds, test server 2 1.034 seconds. I am using a newly created database with identical create table commands and importing identical files to get the data into these 3 servers.

Comment: Killing a MyISAM UPDATE in the middle leaves some rows changes, some not changes.  Consider switching to InnoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause of the difference in performance.

All of the test servers had the default max_seeks_for_key setting of 18446744073709551615, but the setting on the production server with the problem was 500. When I was analysing the slight differences between the servers this difference did not stand out as I assumed this setting was likely to improve performance rather than reduce it.

Answer (score 2):

An `or` condition in a `join` is slow.  I would recommend breaking this into two updates:

```
UPDATE tableA a INNER JOIN
       tableB b
       ON a.id = b.dnum and a.account = b.account
    SET a.status = 0,
    a.apd = NULL
    WHERE a.status = 1;

UPDATE tableA a INNER JOIN
       tableB b
       ON a.id = CONCAT(b.dnum, '\_', b.account, '\_', b.unique))
    SET a.status = 0, a.apd = NULL
    WHERE a.status = 1;
```

You can then speed these with appropriate indexes.  `tableA(status, id, account)` and `tableB(dnum, account)` for the first one.  `tableA(id, status)` for the second one.

Comment: Splitting the queries does not change the performance on the Test server both versions averaged 0.4 seconds over 3 test runs, but the production system actually completes in the same time. Almost implying there is a fault in the OR behaviour on 5.5.31 and not on 5.5.41.

Comment: Since `status` is volatile, it _may_ be unwise to have it in any indexes.